# PHP. How to read a file, if it is writing without a problem with "a+", but is not readable with "r"?

Tags: php, file-get-contents, fread, file-pointer

I have two scripts: one of them writes the value of a variable to a file. In another script, I try to read it. It is written without problems, but it is not readable.
Here I write to a file:

```
$peer_id=2000000001;
$fileLocation = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") . "/peer_id.txt";
$file = fopen($fileLocation,"a+");
fwrite($file, $peer_id);
fclose($file);
```

Here I read the file:

```
$fileLocation = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") . "/peer_id.txt"; 
$file = fopen($fileLocation,"r");
if(file_exists($fileLocation)){
        // Result is TRUE
}
if(is_readable ($file)){
      // Result is FALSE
}
// an empty variables, because the file is not readable
$peer_id = fread($file);
$peer_id = fileread($file);
$peer_id = file_get_contents($file);
fclose($file);
```

The code runs on "sprinthost" hosting, if that makes a difference. There are suspicions that this is because of that hosting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file_get_contents` in short runs the `fopen`, `fread`, and `fclose`. You don't use a pointer with it. You should just use:

```
$peer_id = file_get_contents($fileLocation);
```

That is the same for `is_readable`:

```
if(is_readable($fileLocation)){
    // Result is FALSE
}
```

So full code should be something like:

```
$fileLocation = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") . "/peer_id.txt";
if(file_exists($fileLocation) && is_readable($fileLocation)) {
     $peer_id = file_get_contents($fileLocation);
} else {
    echo 'Error message about file being inaccessible here';
}
```

The `file_get_contents` has an inverse function for writing; https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php. Use that with the `append` constant and you should have the same functionality your first code block had:

```
file_put_contents($fileLocation, $peer_id, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: Thanks! You very helped! It's strange that fread($file), readfile($file) doesn't read anything...

Comment: Not sure about the `fread` issue that should work with a valid pointer... but the functionality you were using was more for PHP4, or when working with large files that can be put entirely into memory. If you can put into memory `file_get_contents` is easier to use.

Comment: For other usage you have `fileread` or `readfile`? The `readfile` goes to output buffer, assignment would be number of bytes it read. If you use `fileread` would need to see that function because is not native.